# Update Ubuntu Server

Tags: updates, security

I am attempting to install security updates for installed packages on  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, however when running sudo apt-get update / upgrade  and dist-upgrade everything comes back clear like it is installed.
However, we run tenable/nessus and we have 40 updates to install which are newer versions. As an example: https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/164946 & https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/152783
How do I get this updated file and then install it?

Comment: It depends on how you've installed it. If packages are not in the Ubuntu repositories, you have to rely on whoever provides them. Obviously, openssl and zlib get updated. Try `apt-get changelog packagename`.

Comment: The question was anwered at [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479493).

Comment: Nessus is only aware of the 'version numbers' of software - it is not aware of Ubuntu level patching/modification like Rapid7's vulnerability assessment and agent tooling is when installed on those systems.  **Do not blindly trust Nessus results, always take the info about the vulnerability it reports (CVE, etc.) and then check the Ubuntu Security site to check if the CVE is patched or not, and then adjust your Nessus report accordingly and reclassify the item or remove it as 'false positive' with the details in teh scan report.

Answer (score 2):

Those examples are both old and already mitigated. It's likely you are already running the patched versions.

1. Look up the CVEs at https://ubuntu.com/security/ to see which packages and versions were secured against the CVE
2. Then use `apt list <packagename>` to confirm that you are running that secured version (or higher).

If you are running older versions than are currently in the Ubuntu repositories, use `apt-cache policy <packagename>` to figure out when/why you introduced a version conflict that prevents updates. Try to avoid those.

Also, keep in mind that stock Ubuntu systems **automatically** install security updates --it's a key feature of Ubuntu-- unless your team turned that feature off or otherwise broke it. You shouldn't need to do anything special to stay secure.

Comment: Hi,
So it is not Tenable I am trying to update it, that's the tool being used for Cyber Essentials + has run a scan and found all 40 missing security updates. The problem is that when running apt-get update/upgrade, etc., there are no updates. When I google for instance OpenSSL to see the latest available versions, there is a newer version available to install online that I am unable to install via apt-get update on the server

Comment: @CraigSummers your comment seems a misplaced response to comments in your Question above. This comment section is about how to improve this answer. This answer tells your exactly which next steps to take for your "40 missing." Either your system is broken (doubtful) or you have a long list of false positives. This answer tells you how to determine each.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Versions:

"Ubuntu, like most other Linux distros, releases security updates by patching specific issues rather than updating whole versions of software."

...

"Sometimes external security vendors doing software version scanning against Ubuntu systems do not check actual package versions, leading to false positives in their scan reports."

It sounds like this is what is happening to you here.